# Triggering action from iWatch in iPhone app to control bluetooth device

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, watchkit

I would like to trigger an action within an iPhone app to control a bluetooth device when the user taps on the iWatch interface. What are the steps needed?

I can add the button on the iWatch and link it to the iWatch interface controller code. However, how can I send the action to the iPhone source code? I have a singleton object that deals with bluetooth communication and lives in the iPhone bundle and I need a way to:

- awake the iPhone app
- pass the action to the relevant logic controller in the iPhone app

Answer (score 2):

You can awake your iphone app with openParentApplication method.

Basically, in your watch extension, you do:

```
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:@{@"action" : @"turnBTON"}
                                       reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {

}
```

And in your AppDelegate you override:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
          reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply `
```

[This tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-open-ios-app-from-watch/) has a simple example, if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the link. It helps me much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WatchKit API to call to your containing iOS App to open and process an action using the

```
openParentApplication:reply:
```

As documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:)

However there is also an Open Source Project - [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) Which tries to run in near runtime communication between a Watch App and the iPhone App.

I am not sure if either of these methods will allow for "background" execution on the iPhone.

Comment: openParentApplication will wake up your host app in the background.